# STL related seg fault in C++ std::string?

Tags: c++

Does anyone point when can the below seg fault occur, as below:
 - heap Corruption
 - Memory leak
 - Flaw in the STL implementation of Strings

```
0xf0f1d672 in std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::allocate(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
```

To give some context, the stack trace is as below:

```
#0  0xf0f1d672 in std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::allocate(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#1  0xf10bdae1 in std::__simple_alloc<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, Calculator*> >, std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0> >::allocate(unsigned int) () from /export/work/install/lib/Plugin.so
```

Comment: That's not much of a stack trace... and not much of a question either...

Comment: "Flaw in the STL implementation of Strings" Yeah, STL is known to provide untested, buggy and badly-designed classes. It can't be trusted.

Comment: @ereOn: +1 for daring to use sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

From your stack trace it appears that you're creating a dynamically loaded `.so` plugin. If the plugin interface uses heap allocation, you must generally make sure that the same instance of the runtime library is used on both sides of the plugin API boundary.

Comment: Thanks Greg.. The model here is that there are separate objects within the binary each having an instance of the plugin. Now, yes the plugin instance is single threaded and does heap allocation.